# Databinding ComboBox to SelectedItem in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have been looking for a solution for my problem for quite some time now, so now I'm just going post some code here!

I'm using MVVM to handle data in my application and the issue concerns the following two ViewModel-classes

```
public class vmProject : vmBase
{
private Project project;


public User Owner
{
    get { return project.Owner; }
    set {project.Owner = value; OnPropertyChanged("Owner"); }
}


public vmProject(Project project)
{
    this.project = project;
}

}

public class User
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string ShortName { get; set; }
public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

I load all the projects into an ObservableCollection and all users into an ObservableCollection.
Now I want to show all the projects in a DataGrid with a ComboBox displaying the ShortName of the user. The datagrid should also have a text-column for displaying the FullName of the Owner.

My problem is, that I can't figure out if I should use a DataGridComboBoxColumn or a DataGridTemplateColumn. And how to use databinding in each of them as well...

When the user selects a new owner in the combobox the model should be updated as well as the FullName-column.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: this articles should help you http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html and http://blog.smoura.com/introducing-the-wpf-toolkit-datagrid/ and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to use a combobox to display the ShortName? Try the autoGenerateColumn and see if you are not happy with what the grid generates for you.

Comment: Instant survey:  If the post tag editor was placed above the title, so that the first thing you do is add tags to your question, would you have been a) more likely b) as likely c) less likely to preface your title with a tag?

Comment: @Will I think that's a great idea actually. In addition to (hopefully) helping keep tags out of question titles, it could also be used to improve the relevance of the "questions with similar titles" search

Comment: @Rachel: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52750/adding-tags-before-title-of-the-question

Comment: @Rachel: wait, wat?  You found the meta discussion and re-added this conversation already?  My mind is full of ....

Comment: @Will lol I mentioned it in SO tavern hoping to get some attention and someone put a 500 bounty on it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an MVVM peron but this is how I would do it without MVVM.  Don't think you need UsersFiltered to be and ObservableCollection.  If UsersAll is an Observable collection it will pick up new rows when you select a new name.

```
 bind the grid to a filtered list 


 public List<User> UsersFiltered 
 {
    get
    {
         return UsersAll.Where(usr => user = SelectedCBUser).ToList();
    }
 {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses a ComboBox in a Template column. It assumes that your `UserCollection` is part of the same `DataContext` that holds the `ProjectsCollection`

```
<DataGridColumn>
    <DataGridColumn.Template>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                          Path=DataContext.UserCollection}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Owner}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="ShortName" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridColumn.Template>
</DataGridColumn>
```

When WPF compares objects for `SelectedValue`, it compares them by reference. So unless your `User` object on each Property is the exact same reference in memory as the one in your `UserCollection`, this value will return false and the item will not be selected. One way around this is to [overwrite the `.ToString()` method](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/) of the `User` class so the items are consider equal if their ID fields match.

Another way is to use the `SelectedValuePath` and bind the `SelectedValue` to a generic data type such as an int `UserId` field.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
               Path=DataContext.UserCollection}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.Id}"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          DisplayMemberPath="ShortName" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the above solution would solve my problem. In order to update the FullName-column I would think that I needed to bind SelectedItem (not SelectedValue). I can't set a new Id for the Owner in vmProject-object, this wouldn't update the actual Owner-User-object. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @ChristianTang You can use `SelectedItem`, but take note that the `Owner` object should reference an item in the `UserCollection` for it to work, or you need to overwrite the `ToString()` method of the `User` class so it considers the two classes equal if their `ID` is the same. By default they will only be considered equal if they reference the same object in memory